# Is the scheduler built into the kernel a program or a process?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

I looked up the CPU scheduler source code built into the kernel.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/kernel/sched

But I have a question.
There are mixed opinions on the cpu scheduler on the Internet.

1. I saw an opinion that CPU scheduler is a process.

Question: If so, when ps-ef on Linux, the scheduler process should be visible. It was difficult to find the PID and name of the scheduler process.
The PID for the CPU scheduler process is not on the internet either. However, the PID 0 SWAPPER process is called SCHED, but in Linux, PID 0 functions as an idle process.

2. I saw an opinion that CPU scheduler is not a process.
   CPU scheduler is a passive source code built into the kernel, and user processes frequently enter the kernel and rotate the source code.

Question: How does the user process execute the kernel's scheduler source code on its own?
What if you created a user program without adding a system call using the scheduler of the kernel?
How does the user process self-rotate the scheduler in the kernel without such code?

Comment: I'm not good at English because I'm a foreigner.
Thank you for changing the title to a better one.

Comment: It is more like a set of functions: `process* get_next_process(); void run_process(process* which_process);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 similar questions ([The opinion that the scheduler built into the kernel is the program and the opinion that it is the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422980/the-opinion-that-the-scheduler-built-into-the-kernel-is-the-program-and-the-opin) and [I want to know how to implement the cpu scheduling process in Linux operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71404014/i-want-to-know-how-to-implement-the-cpu-scheduling-process-in-linux-operating-sy)) so I'll answer for both of these here.

The answer is that it doesn't work that way at all. The scheduler is not called by user mode processes by using system calls. The scheduler isn't a system call. There are timers that are programmed to throw interrupts after some time has elapsed. Timers are accessed using registers that are memory in RAM often called memory mapped IO (MMIO). You write to some position in RAM specified by the ACPI tables (https://wiki.osdev.org/ACPI) and it will allow to control the chips in the CPU or external PCI devices (PCI is everything nowadays).

When the timer reaches 0, it will trigger an interrupt. Interrupts are thrown by hardware (the CPU). The CPU thus includes special mechanism to let the OS determine the position at which it will jump on interrupt (https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table). Interrupts are used by the CPU to notify the OS that an event happened. Without interrupts, the OS would have to reserve at least one core of the processor for a special kernel process that would constantly poll the registers of peripherals and other things. It would be impossible to implement. Also, if user mode processes did the scheduler system call by themselves, the kernel would be slave to user mode because it wouldn't be able to tell if a process is finished and processes could be selfish over CPU time.

I didn't look at the source code but I think the scheduler is also often called on some IO completion (also on interrupt but not always on timer interrupt). I am quite sure that the scheduler must not be preempted. That is interrupts (and other things) will be disabled while the schedule() function runs.

I don't think you can call the scheduler a process (not even a kernel thread). The scheduler can be called by kernel threads that are created by interrupts due to bottom half processing. In bottom half processing, the top "half" of the interrupt handler runs fast and efficiently while the bottom "half" is added to the queue of processes and runs when the scheduler decides it should be scheduled. This has the effect of creating some kernel threads. The scheduler can thus be called from kernel threads but not always from bottom half of interrupts. There has to be a mechanism to call the scheduler without the scheduler having to schedule the task itself. Otherwise, the kernel will stop functioning.

Comment: Thank you so much, professor.
It's the same as what the university professor taught me.
When the professor taught me CPU scheduling, he explained about the timer and interrupt.
I wanted to study that explanation again later.
However, no matter how much I searched the Internet, it was hard to find the content.
I searched online and asked questions for weeks without exaggeration.
Professor, I love you. And I deleted the overlapping questions.
Thank you so much.

Comment: To find the explanation, I looked up the English text site and signed up for Stack Over Flow.
Thank you again.

Comment: No problem happy that it helped out.

Comment: Thank you so much, professor.
You're such a kind and cool person.